# What does one question mark following a variable declaration mean?

Tags: c#, .net

Whilst playing around in an open source project, my attempt to *ToString* a DateTime object was thwarted by the compiler. When I jumped to the definition, I saw this:

```
public DateTime? timestamp;
```

Might someone please enlighten me on what this is called and why it might be useful?

Comment: +1 for compiler-thwarting now being an accepted verb.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is a [nullable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types). Nullable types allow [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) (e.g. `int`s and structures like DateTime) to contain null.

The `?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<DateTime>` since it's used so often.

To call `ToString()`:

```
if (timstamp.HasValue) {        // i.e. is not null
    return timestamp.Value.ToString();
}
else {
    return "<unknown>";   // Or do whatever else that makes sense in your context
}
```

Comment: you could use `??` operator instead of if/else no ?

Comment: @v.oddou: Yes, although in this example the resulting object is a DateTime that we want to format as a string (and it doesn't really make sense to have a default date/time if there isn't one stored in the nullable structure).

Comment: @v.oddou Idunno - that would be awful lot of question mark-y syntactic sugar for one varibale, don't you think?

Comment: @Cameron what I don't understand is, your proposal is exactly what MSDN says the [overloaded `Nullable<>.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket(v=vs.110).aspx) is supposed to do... (?) QUOTE: _"The text representation of the value of the current Nullable<T> object if the HasValue property is true, or an empty string ("") if the HasValue property is false."_

Comment: @CodeJockey: Huh, seems you're right. You could simply call `ToString()` directly in this case. The point of my example, though, was not to rewrite `ToString()`, but rather to show how a nullable variable might be used. I'll change the string in the `else` to make it less silly ;-)

Comment: That makes more sense as an "overload", but it still leaves me wondering how the OP had an issue to begin with: _"...my attempt to ToString a DateTime object..."_ - might have had a different issue, but it was apparently helpful to the OP to know what the `?` was... :-)

Comment: Not sure for OP, but I had a similar issue: `DateTime` supported `DateTime.ToString("M/d/yyyy");` but when it was a `DateTime?`, there was no overload `ToString("some string")` - only `ToString()`. That was somewhat of a problem for me. Is that expected?

Comment: @mmcrae: Yes, that's expected. `Nullable<T>` provides a uniform API regardless of `T`.

Comment: so I guess only way to get the real `DateTime.ToString("M/d/yyyy")` would be to check `HasValue` and then call  `Value` to get actual `DateTime`?

Comment: @mmcrae: Yes, that's right. It's up to you to decide what string representation you want when the `DateTime?` is null.

Answer (score 9):

`?` makes a value type (`int`, `bool`, `DateTime`, or any other `struct` or `enum`) nullable via the `System.Nullable<T>` type. `DateTime?` means that the variable is a `System.Nullable<DateTime>`. You can assign a `DateTime` or the value `null` to that variable. To check if the variable has a value, use the `HasValue` property and to get the actual value, use the `Value` property.

Answer (score 5):

That is a shortcut for `Nullable<DateTime>`.  Value types, like `DateTime` cannot be null; `Nullable<>` wraps the value type so that you have an object with a `HasValue` property and other convenient features.

Answer (score -2):

it is nullable datetime